# installing ruby/gnome2 on ruby1.9

Tags: ruby, installation, gnome, ruby-1.9, gtk2

My purpose is to install ruby/gnome2 and make it work with ruby1.9 on Ubuntu9.10.

I already have ruby/gnome2 working with ruby1.8, but I need to make it work with ruby1.9. I also have ruby1.9 working. When I run within ruby-gnome2-all-0.19.3:

ruby1.9 extconf.rb

it eventually gives me:

Target libraries: glib, gdkpixbuf, pango, atk, gtk, gconf, libglade
Ignored libraries: gnomeprintui, panel-applet, gtksourceview, gtksourceview2, bonoboui, bonobo, libart, goocanvas, rsvg, gnomeprint, gstreamer, vte, gnomevfs, poppler, gnomecanvas, gtkglext, gnome, gtkmozembed, gtkhtml2

so it seems some packages failed to be installed. When I look for the log for example for the gnomeprintui part, it exits after returning:

cheking for libgnomeprinrui-2.2... no

but apt-get says I have the newest version of it. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, probably, need to install devel package for libgnomeprinrui.